# Visual Studio Publish Web Dialogue takes excessive time to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dialog, visual-studio-2015, web-publishing

Whenever I launch the Visual Studio 2015 Publish Web Dialogue (or Visual Studio 2013, both have the same issue) for a *specific* project, it takes ~20-30 seconds for it to open. Just as well, when I switch between publish profiles it takes the same amount of time *when I switch to a specific one*. When I switch to Profile A in the list (from Profile B) it takes the same amount of time as it does when it launches the dialogue itself. When I switch from Profile A to the Profile B it doesn't take any time at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I lose 20-30 minutes a day of development on this issue alone.

I have inspected the XML (`.pubxml`) on both profiles, and they are identical except for the name of the site on the server, and the `Web.config` SQL string transformation result. (They both publish to the *same* server endpoint, both are precompiled with all pages/controls set to one assembly, the only difference is the name of the profile and what the name of the site is.)

I also inspected the profile `.user` file, and both are identical *once again*. I am at a loss as to what could be the issue here.

Do note that publishing does not take a lot of time at all. It takes just as long for Profile A to publish as Profile B does.

Also, this issue was present even on my old Visual Studio 2015 installation before I reinstalled Windows completely. (And I did reinstall Windows *entirely* when I upgraded to Windows 10.)

I am open to any and all ideas, I might reinstall Visual Studio 2015 **again** to see if the issue goes away.

Further notes: while it is loading the dialogue, it locks Visual Studio up *entirely*.

Update: reinstalling Visual Studio entirely did not rectify the issue.

Another update: Occasionally Visual Studio crashes completely when opening the dialogue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR:** As a workaround for this problem, find your `DbContext` class which inherit from `IdentityDbContext<>` and change base class constructor from `base("DefaultConnection")` to `base("DefaultConnection", false)` and **do a full rebuild** on your solution. That will disable checking against Entity 1.0.0 which causes timeouts when run from Publish Web.

**The results of debugging:** After *much* debugging, we found the root cause.

1. When you run Publish Web with Code-First used in your project, it will want to enumerate available connection strings in order to detect your Databases.
2. To do that, it will call your `DbContext` class, locating it with reflection and calling it inside VisualStudio's process.
3. Unfortunately, since it's executed within VisualStudio, `ConnectionManager` will use `devenv.exe.config` instead of your `web.config`, hence your `web.config` with its connection strings is ignored.
4. As soon as you call `IdentityDbContext<>` in the form of  `base("DefaultConnection")`, [it will call](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-rtm-140221/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) `base("DefaultConnection", true)`, which (according to the second parameter) [will try to detect](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-rtm-140221/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) whether your database uses Identity 1.0.0 schema.
5. In order to do that, it will try to connect to your database, identified by the name of connection passed to `IdentityDbContext<>` (usually it will be `"DefaultConnection"`)
6. Since the `web.config` is not loaded, the connection string with such name would be unavailable.
7. For unavailable connection string, Entity would call `DefaultConnectionFactory`. Again, you can't customize it, as `web.config` is not loaded. By default, `DefaultConnectionFactory` will try to connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS` with `Initial Catalog` = your connection name, likely resulting in the following connection string:

   ```
   Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
   ```
8. If you do not have SQL Express installed, that will result in SQL exception, which will retry futile attempts to connect until timeout expires.

So, the culprit is Publish Web, which incorrectly runs assembly through reflection without loading the corresponding `web.config`.

---

---

**Debugging recipe we have started with:**
Let's figure what's happening inside.

1. Make a few dumps **during** the freeze (let's say a dump every 2-3 seconds). To make a dump, I think the simplest way is this: download & run [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), and use `Context Menu on Visual Studio's process | Create Dump | Create Minidump...`
2. Analyze dumps. The simplest way would be to use [OSR's instant analyze](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze)
3. Inspect stacks in the dumps (starting from `STACK_TEXT` in analysis results)
4. The names of functions on stack can already tell you what's wrong.
5. If this guide does not help you, I will need to see the dumps myyself. Please be aware that dumps will contain portions of VS's memory, which could contain some personal information, such as file paths.

**Update**

Now that OSR's analyze failed to analyze the stacks in dumps, it seems we'll have to do it the hard way.

**One-time preparation**

1. Install `Debugging Tools For Windows` as part of [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395) (clear all other checkboxes to not install what you don't need)
2. Run `WinDBG (X86)` from installed package
3. In `File | Symbol File Path...` write

   ```
   srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```
4. Press `File | Save workspace`

**Analyzing a dump**

1. In WinDBG, press `File | Open crash dump...` and open your dump.
2. In the edit box at the bottom, write `!analyze -v` and press Enter.
3. Inspect the stack.

Comment: I've done all that, and now it shows what methods/classes/etc are executing, and it looks like the issue is in Entity Framework somewhere. The first items on the `MANAGED_STACK` section are SQL and Entity Framework lines. Very curious. (The very first line looks like a call to `Sleep`.)

Comment: [Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/EBrown8534/74b524cdf40eb984ee55) with the `MANAGED_STACK` information on it, if it helps any. I think there's something up with the SQL stuff it's trying to do.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as it led me to the root problem (there is a SQL exception going on, according to this dump), I really appreciate all the help, effort and insight!

Comment: The exception object is really interesting, and SQL connection timeout, which nicely correlates with freeze you're experiencing.

Comment: Yeah, it happens right in the middle of the freeze, so I'm going to try a few things and see what happens. Again, I really appreciate all the help, I'd have never found this myself. :)

Comment: Do you understand which SQL server is that about? Can you try accessing it directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91932/discussion-between-codeguard-and-ebrown).

Comment: regarding your TL;DR: I don't have any Context, which inherits `IdentityDbContext`, just `DbContext` itself is inherited. Also I use `base("conncectionString")`, which is not overloaded by base(String, Boolean). Is there a workaround for that constellation? (EF 6.1.3)

Comment: It's been a while. Please post a new question, providing code snippets for what you said, and cross-link these two questions. You will probably get help sooner then I'm able to look into it.